# apache/httpd responds slower under EL6.1 than EL5.6 (CentOS)

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, rhel6, centos5

I've read through other threads on performance differences between RHEL 6 and RHEL 5, but none seem a tight match to mine.

My issue manifests itself in slightly slower average response time (20ms) per request.  I have about 10/10 servers of the same hardware spec with CentOS 6.1 and CentOS 5.6.  The issue is consistent across the group.

I am running Ruby on Rails with Passenger.

- Apache config is identical (checked out from the same SVN repo)
- Ruby and Passenger are identical builds.
- Application is identical and being served traffic round robin.
- mod_worker

An interesting clue from server-status:  The CentOS 6.1 servers have a steady 20-40 threads in the "Reading Request" state while the CentOS 5.6 servers have around 1. I'm graphing this so I can see it trend over time.

I also have a bunch of much newer machines that are significantly faster and are running CentOS 6.1.  They dust all the older machines in response time, but I can see they also have a steady 20-40 threads in the "Reading Request" state. This makes me believe I can get their response time down, if I can figure out what is holding up these requests.

My gut is telling me that I need to tune some network setting in sysctl, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: ooh. interesting one. There are bonkers loads of metrics and settings that you could pull here to find out.

Comment: How many requests per second are you serving avg? whats the current cache and buffers?

Comment: each individual server gets to around 40/sec

Comment: there is a good amount of free memory, if that's what you are asking

CentOS6:
MemTotal:        8061920 kB
MemFree:         1898468 kB
Buffers:           92748 kB
Cached:          2422552 kB

CentOS 5.6:
MemTotal:      8174968 kB
MemFree:       1107736 kB
Buffers:        147204 kB
Cached:        4750620 kB

Comment: I would probably dive into the guts of apache and see what syscalls these server-status statuses correspond to, at the moment I am only commenting because I can't spare the time, but if you are still at a loss later in the week ill take a look when i am back in the dc

Comment: Cool Tom,  I just did a side-by-side sysctl -a and didn't find much.  Apache is my next step.  thanks!

Comment: Apache versions?

Comment: CentOS6 uses 2.2.15 and CentOS5 uses httpd-2.2.3

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

One FAQ in this area is that memory mgmt in RHEL6 is different and mulit-threaded apps can suffer.  Try running apache under MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=1 and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Wild shot #1: Any chance you're logging hostnames instead of IP addresses? If yes is that on both? If yes is one of them running nscd?

Wild shot #2: Is LDAP involved in any way there? I.e. is the apache or any other component of the request running as an ldap user?